# How to make a left join, in which the the row taken from "data B" is different than the row in which the id is?

Tags: r

I have a data frame "A" with two columns, 
the first has names of cities(unique values), the second has NA, which I want to fill with unemployment.

data frame "B" has a Column with city names, but the unemployment isnt in the same row, to be precise, it is always 1 row below.

How would you merge this two data, so that R looks at the first column on data frame "A", finds its match on data frame "B", and replaces the NA from the second column of data frame "A" with the value 1 row below the row in which the match is made.

Here are some summarized version of how data frame A and B would look like.

```
names= c("Bogotá", "Medellín")
data_frame_A= as.data.frame(names, ncol=1)
colnames(data_frame_A)= "city"
data_frame_A$Unemployment = NA
data_frame_A
```

data frame B looks something like this

```
names= c("Bogotá", "life_exp","Unemployment","Medellín","life_exp","Unemployment")
data_frame_B= as.data.frame(names, ncol=1)
colnames(data_frame_B)= "city"
data_frame_B$column_20 = runif(6, 0.5, 0.8)
data_frame_B
```

How would you merge this two data then?

Comment: Do you always have two rows between each city in `data_frame_B`? Or do the available variables per city change

Comment: Alternatively, do you know that all cities in data_frame_B appear in data_frame_A? or have some other way to know which rows in B are new cities instead of just reading them?

Comment: 1. Its always the same number of rows after the city name appears until the unemployment data shows up.
2. yes, all cities o appear.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that checks if each `city` in `data_frame_B` is in `data_frame_A` to assign rows to each city. We make a new column that has the actual city name, and then we can `spread` the variables out into their own columns.  You can join back on to `data_frame_A` after this if there are columns there that you need.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data_frame_A <- structure(list(city = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Bogotá", "Medellín"), class = "factor"), Unemployment = c(NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
data_frame_B <- structure(list(city = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Bogotá", "life_exp", "Medellín", "Unemployment"), class = "factor"), column_20 = c(0.653383622108959, 0.685130500583909, 0.616564040770754, 0.731770524056628, 0.53738643436227, 0.571727990615182)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

data_frame_B %>%
  group_by(city_id = cumsum(city %in% data_frame_A$city)) %>%
  mutate(city_name = first(city)) %>%
  filter(city_name != city) %>%
  spread(city, column_20)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   city_id [2]
#>   city_id city_name life_exp Unemployment
#>     <int> <fct>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1       1 Bogotá       0.685        0.617
#> 2       2 Medellín     0.537        0.572
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Setting the random seed in the Note at the end to make the data reproducible we can use the following double left join:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.city, b2.[column_20]
  from [data_frame_A] as a 
  left join [data_frame_B] as b using(city)
  left join [data_frame_B] as b2 on b2.rowid = b.rowid + 1")
```

giving:

```
      city column_20
1   Bogotá 0.7364915
2 Medellín 0.7821402
```

### Note

```
set.seed(123)

names= c("Bogotá", "Medellín")
data_frame_A= as.data.frame(names, ncol=1)
colnames(data_frame_A)= "city"
data_frame_A$Unemployment = NA

names= c("Bogotá", "life_exp","Unemployment","Medellín","life_exp","Unemployment")
data_frame_B= as.data.frame(names, ncol=1)
colnames(data_frame_B)= "city"
data_frame_B$column_20 = runif(6, 0.5, 0.8)
```